# Python script to replace GitHub password with tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

I manage a fleet of IoT devices.

As for now, GitHub announced that the username-password authentication would be deprecative soon, so I have to change the password on each device to the GitHub access token.
I store the new token at AWS secrets manager. And those are the scripts to extract the new token and implement it on the device.

update_github_token.py

```
from get_aws_secret_manager import get_secret
import subprocess

SECRET_NAME = 'prod/GitHub/Token'
GITHUB_TOKEN_KEY = 'droneGitHubToken'
GITHUB_USER_NAME = 'danAairlines'
GITHUB_REPO_OWNER = 'Aairlinesfox'


def get_github_tokken():
    github_secret_dict = get_secret(SECRET_NAME)
    return github_secret_dict[GITHUB_TOKEN_KEY]


def build_token_github_url():
    github_token = get_github_tokken()
    return f'https://{GITHUB_USER_NAME}:{github_token}@github.com/{GITHUB_REPO_OWNER}/drone.git'


def update_drone_github_url():
    github_url = build_token_github_url()
    subprocess.run(f'sudo git remote set-url origin {github_url}', shell=True, check=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_drone_github_url()
```

The second module is AWS script, as appears on their website. I just modified the get_secret function by adding args. And at the end of the file, I added:

```
secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
        return secret
```

get_aws_secret_manager.py

````
# If you need more information about configurations or implementing the sample code, visit the AWS docs:
# https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/

import boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json


def get_secret(aws_secret_name: str, aws_region_name: str = "eu-central-1"):
    secret_name = aws_secret_name
    region_name = aws_region_name

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
            return secret

        else:
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])```
````